# How to prevent Intellij from treating Scala warning as error?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying out Intellij on a mixed Java/Scala project. Build is failing with errors like this:

> Error: scala:
>   /home/kevin/ij/backend/srctest/com/example/package/DoStuffTest.java:35:
>   warning: [deprecation] OldStuffList in com.example.package has been
>   deprecated

I'm not able to find any setting related to treating warning as errors. I'd like these to be reported as warnings (because indeed, they are warnings), but not prevent the build from completing.

Comment: I recommend you define your project in SBT, use the `sbt-idea` plug-in to generate the IDEA project and built in SBT. Then you can control things like deprecation warning and language level all in one place. I like IDEA as development tool, but not as a build tool.

Comment: even with an sbt project, intellij still make its own build. I have this problem on one computer and not on the other...

Answer (score 3):

In the scala compiler settings, check that there is no `-Xfatal-warnings`
This option makes scalac treat warning as error.

Note that I had this problem after a colleague added this option in the `build.sbt` of an sbt project. Intellij then added it to its scala compiler settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit alt-enter on the highlighted error,  it should at least give you a dropdown option called "Disable inspection" which should let you turn that off for that instance or all Deprecated errors.  This doesn't really solve your problem, but it might at least get you past it.